# Python: passing an object from the decorator itself

Tags: python, object, decorator

I try to pass class attributes inside a decorator. In a future this will permit me to access to few definition and hide some useless code.

The code must work like this:

```
def division_error(The_Object_Iteself):
    def inner_function(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except ZeroDivisionError as err:
                print(f"{The_Object_Iteself.__name__}: impossible division by zero")
        return wrapper
    return inner_function


class Tast:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @division_error(The_Object_Iteself)
    def divide(self):
        return self.a / self.b


tast = Tast(12, 1)
print(tast.divide())
```

They have another possibility, it's to access it from the decorator itself by not passing the object as arguments of the decorator like the code next

```
from functools import wraps


def division_error(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            function(*args, **kwargs)
        except ZeroDivisionError as err:
            print(f"{Tast.__object__.__name__}: Division by zero error")
    return wrapper


class Tast:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @division_error
    def divide(self):
        return self.a / self.b


tast = Tast(12, 0)
print(tast.divide())
```

I'm not sure of the manner who can do this, otherwise, I do not now how to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve? What *output* do you expect for this? What is ``The_Object_Iteself`` supposed to be – should it be the ``Tast`` class, or a ``Tast`` instance  (i.e. ``self``)? Are you aware the ``self`` will be passed to ``wrapper`` as ``args[0]``?

Answer (score 1):

`self` instance can be captured inside *wrapper*. It's first parameter - *args[0]*. However, this approach works only when wrapping class methods.

```
def division_error(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        instance = args[0]

        try:
            function(*args, **kwargs)
        except ZeroDivisionError as err:
            print(f"{instance.__class__.__name__}: Division by zero error")
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Note that this does *not* work when wrapping classmethods - they only receive the class, not the instance. It only works on regular methods.